# How do I push an angularfire (angular+firebase) project to heroku?

Tags: angularjs, heroku, firebase, angularfire

The closest tutorial on heroku to what I'm doing is the node tutorial, but that isn't quite right for my purposes. I've got an angularfire project, with no node stuff going on. How do I handle this? Maybe I don't even need heroku? What's a better way to get my stuff online?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're already using Firebase check out Firebase hosting. It's free for the developer plan and as easy as 'firebase deploy' once you have the dev tools installed.

Here's a link to the hosting docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/

If you want to go the heroku route just set up a small Express server or the like and follow along with their tutorial!

Comment: Have you ever had a problem with google fonts through firebase's hosting? I'm able to see my google font locally but online, it's stuck on sans-serif.

Comment: Check out https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html, especially the headers section. It sounds like a CORS issue.